# I do not understand why my code is counting aces as 11

Tags: java

I have to create a Java program for blackjack, and the last part of what I was doing is making aces count as 1 when necessary. But for some reason even though I use the code

```
 if (deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck).getValue().equals("Ace")){
                        if ((dealerHandValue += deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck).getValueInt()) >21){

                            dealerHandValue += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        dealerHandValue += deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck).getValueInt();
                        cardNumberInDeck++;
                    }
```

(and switch dealerHandValue for playerHandvalue when necesarry)
I still get it that when I run the program, Aces are counting as 11 and busting the person who gets it.

```
public class BlackJack {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.shuffle();
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String a = "";
        int hitstand;      
        int cardNumberInDeck = 0;

        while (cardNumberInDeck < 52){
            System.out.println("Do you want to play blackjack? (1) Yes (2) No");
            int game = input.nextInt();
            if (game == 2) {
                break;
            }

            int playerHandValue = 0;
            int dealerHandValue = 0;
            System.out.println ("Your card is " + deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck).toString() + " and " +
            deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck +1).toString()) ;
            cardNumberInDeck+=2;
            System.out.println ("Your Dealers cards are " + deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck).toString() + 
            " and the other card is hidden");
            cardNumberInDeck+=2;

            playerHandValue = ((deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck -4).getValueInt() + deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck - 3).getValueInt()));
            dealerHandValue = deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck - 2).getValueInt();

            if (playerHandValue == 22){
                playerHandValue = 12;
            }

            if (dealerHandValue == 22){
                dealerHandValue = 12;
            }

            System.out.println("Your hand value is " + playerHandValue);
            System.out.println("The dealer's hand value is " + dealerHandValue + "+");

            if (playerHandValue == 21){
                System.out.println("You win, you have blackjack");
                continue;
            }
            if ((dealerHandValue == 21)){
                System.out.println("You Lose, the dealer has blackjack");
                continue;
            }

            if (playerHandValue == 21 && dealerHandValue == 21){
                System.out.println("You push, both you and the dealer have blackjacl");
                continue;
            }

            boolean g = true;
            boolean t = true;
            int ticker = 0;
            while(g == true){


            System.out.println("Would you like to hit(1) or stand(2):");
            hitstand = input.nextInt();

            if (hitstand == 1){
                System.out.println("Your hit and get a " + deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck).toString());

                if (deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck).getValue().equals("Ace")){
                    if ((playerHandValue += deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck).getValueInt()) >21){
                        playerHandValue += 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    playerHandValue += deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck).getValueInt();
                    cardNumberInDeck++;
                }

                System.out.println("Your hand value is " + playerHandValue);
                if (playerHandValue > 21) {
                    System.out.println("You lost, because you busted ");
                    g = false;
                    if (cardNumberInDeck > 45){
                        System.out.println("The deck has to few cards. Reshuffling cards");
                        deck.shuffle();
                        cardNumberInDeck = 0;
                    }
                }
                ticker++;
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("The dealers hand is " + deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck - (2 + ticker)).toString() + " and " +
                deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck - (1 + ticker)).toString());

                dealerHandValue += deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck - (1 + ticker)).getValueInt();

                while (dealerHandValue < 17){
                    System.out.println("The dealer hits and gets a " + deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck).toString() + ". ");

                    if (deck.getCard(cardNumberInDeck).getValue().equals("Ace")){
                        if ((dealerHandValue += deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck).getValueInt()) >21){

                            dealerHandValue += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        dealerHandValue += deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck).getValueInt();
                        cardNumberInDeck++;
                    }

                    cardNumberInDeck++;
                    if (dealerHandValue > 21){
                        System.out.println("The dealer's hand value is: " + dealerHandValue);
                        System.out.println("The dealer busted, you win");
                        t = false;
                        g = false;
                        if (cardNumberInDeck > 45){
                            System.out.println("The deck has to few cards. Reshuffling cards");
                            deck.shuffle();
                            cardNumberInDeck = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (t == true){
                    if (dealerHandValue < playerHandValue){
                        System.out.println("Your hand value was " +  playerHandValue + " the dealer's hand value is " +
                        dealerHandValue);
                        System.out.println("You win, your hand was better");
                        g = false;
                        if (cardNumberInDeck >45){
                            System.out.println("The deck has to few cards. Reshuffling cards");
                            deck.shuffle();
                            cardNumberInDeck = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(dealerHandValue > playerHandValue){
                        System.out.println("Your hand value was " +  playerHandValue + " the dealer's hand value is " +
                        dealerHandValue);
                        System.out.println("You lose, your hand was worse");
                        g = false;
                        if (cardNumberInDeck > 45){
                            System.out.println("The deck has to few cards. Reshuffling cards");
                            deck.shuffle();
                            cardNumberInDeck = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (dealerHandValue == playerHandValue){
                        System.out.println("Your hand value was " +  playerHandValue + " the dealer's hand value is " +
                        dealerHandValue);
                        System.out.println("You push, your hands were equal");
                        g = false;
                        if (cardNumberInDeck > 45){
                            System.out.println("The deck has to few cards. Reshuffling cards");
                            deck.shuffle();
                            cardNumberInDeck = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ((dealerHandValue += deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck).getValueInt()) >21)` performs addition with **assignment** (and then tests value)... You probably didn't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, `if ((dealerHandValue += deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck).getValueInt()) >21)` will add **and** assign.

Use:

```java
if ((dealerHandValue + deck.toInt(cardNumberInDeck).getValueInt()) >21){

                            dealerHandValue += 1;
                        }
```

Replacing `+=` with `+` will only return the sum of the two variables, without assigning (and changing) the original value. `x += y` is a short form of `x = x + y`.